# How do I import a module whose name clashes with a module in my package?

Tags: python, import

I have several python modules in a directory.

In the same directory, I have a package `tests`.

I would quite like to name the modules in `tests` the same as the modules that they contain tests for, although of course it isn't critical.

So, in `tests.foo` I naively write `import foo`. This isn't working so well - it imports `tests.foo`, not top-level `foo`.

Can I do what I want, or do I just have to call the test module `test_foo`?

Sorry if this is obvious or a dupe, my search-fu has failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`test_foo.py` seems like an appropriate solution in this case.

If you don't rename the test modules then make the `tests` directory into Python package (add `tests/__init__.py` file) and use [absolute imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import 
import foo                   # import global foo.py, the first foo.py in sys.path
import tests.foo as test_foo # import tests/foo.py
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the full package path like this:

```
--Package
   |-- __init__.py
   |-- foo.py
   |
   |-- tests
   |    | -- __init__.py
        | -- foo.py
```

in `tests/foo.py` do

```
from Package import foo
```

And i think this part of the documentation can interest you : http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports

Comment: Thanks, but "ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package". This is Python 2.6, if it makes any difference. You're probably right that I should have put everything in a top-level package in the first place. I'm uncertain if that change now would be painless.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: sorry i meant use the full package path to import the `foo` module, i edit it i hope now it's clear