# Python: errors loading numpy and matplotlib

Tags: python, module, load

This is an odd problem. I have Python script which imports numpy and matplotlib.

If I put those scripts into /usr/local/bin, I can load the modules and run my scripts with no problem.

But if I have those scripts in my "work" directory, I get errors.

This is also true if I use python in interactive mode:

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/bin
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 10 2016, 12:56:26) 
[GCC 5.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import matplotlib
>>>
```

No problems.

However, if I go to my work directory, I have problems:

```
$ pwd
/home/Administrator/Documents/Projects/MOCC/rads
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 10 2016, 12:56:26) 
[GCC 5.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 170, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from numpy.testing import Tester
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .utils import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tempfile import mkdtemp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator/Documents/Projects/MOCC/rads/io.py", line 63, in <module>
    SEEK_CUR = 1
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator/Documents/Projects/MOCC/rads/io.py", line 58, in main

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loadtxt'
```

This is cygwin on MS Windows.

Comment: Do you have a python file inside your work directory that shadows a name of another module or package from a library you want to use?

Comment: @languitar Yes and this is probably io.py file, as stacktrace told you check what is going on with `File "/cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator/Documents/Projects/MOCC/rads/io.py", line 58`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I import a module whose name clashes with a module in my package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816595/how-do-i-import-a-module-whose-name-clashes-with-a-module-in-my-package)

Comment: I have the following python files in the work directory:

`cf.py
d.py
d1.py
df.py
example.py
inout.py
interp.py
ma.py
ma1.py
p.py
plot0.py
plot1.py
s.py
sg.py
s-g.py
smooth.py
smooth1.py
txttoimg.py`

There is no `io.py` in the work directory.